# Rxjava, using .zip to merge two livedata objects

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use rxjava .zip to merge two livedata objects. This is what I have so far.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.util.Consumer;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;


import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myapplication.API.model.OrderRows;
import com.example.myapplication.API.model.Orders;


import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button myButt;
    private MainViewModel mvw;
    private TextView myView;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mvw = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        myView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        myButt.setOnClickListener(this);
        final Observer<Orders> obsOrders = new Observer<Orders>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Orders orders) {
                Log.i("order obs", "order obs");
            }
        };
        final Observer<OrderRows> obsOrderRow = new Observer<OrderRows>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(OrderRows orders) {
                Log.i("orderRows obs", "orderRow obs");
            }
        };
        mvw.getAllOrders().observe(this,obsOrders);
        mvw.getAllOrderRows().observe(this,obsOrderRow);

        Observable.zip(obsOrderRow,obsOrders,mergeItems())
                .subscribe(printer());


    }
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@NonNull
private BiFunction<OrderRows, Orders, String> mergeItems() {
    return new BiFunction<OrderRows, Orders, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(OrderRows orderRows, Orders orders) {
            return "asd";
        }
    };
}
@NonNull
private Consumer<String> printer() {
    return new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {
            Log.i("merged",s);
        }
    };
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                Log.i("button","clicked");
                mvw.updateOrderData(); // calls for new values to be fetched
                mvw.updateOrderRowData();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the .zip function when I try to run this I get the following error.

> error: no suitable method found for
>   zip(Observer,Observer,BiFunction)
>           Observable.zip(obsOrderRow,obsOrders,mergeItems())
>                     ^

Added the imports aswell so you guys can see.

Comment: add whole code with imports, I think you are using wrong Observable or wrong BiFunction; what's the signature of the Observable.zip that you used?

Comment: done. Added the imports in the main thread.

Comment: you still did not add import of "Observable", please add

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong `BiFunction`.

You have:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
```

while [zip](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-boolean-) takes [io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/BiFunction.html).